# Encountering HttpError 403 and 500 When Using Google Sheets API with Service Account

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api, http-error

I'm developing a Python application aimed at appending data to a Google Sheet via the Google Sheets API. Despite ensuring public access through the sheet's sharing settings and verifying the service account's permissions, I'm faced with HttpError 403 and HttpError 500, indicating permission issues and internal errors, respectively.

The problem arises when calling the spreadsheets.values.append method using the googleapiclient library in Python. Initially, the HttpError 403 suggests a permissions issue, which is perplexing since the spreadsheet is set to public. Following this, a HttpError 500 points to an internal server error.

Attempts to Resolve:
Confirmed the spreadsheet's public sharing settings.
Regenerated and utilized a new service account key.
Checked Google Sheets API quota limits, which are within acceptable bounds.
Temporarily disabled proxy settings to eliminate potential network issues.
Expected Outcome: The data is appended to the designated range within the spreadsheet seamlessly.

Actual Outcome: Both HttpError 403 and HttpError 500 are encountered, obstructing the data appendage process.

Question: What could be the root cause of these errors, and how can they be resolved to ensure successful data appendage to my Google Sheet via the service account? Is there a permissions or configuration step I might have overlooked?